# Stop Alert Refreshing the whole view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view and I want to show an alert which displays additional information, however the issue is that when the alert is dismissed, it refreshes the whole view and navigates the user back up to the root view (because the state variable showFutherInfo changes when the alert is dismissed). I don't want this to happen.

A VERY simplified version of code looks like this:

```
struct PledgesView: View {
    @State var showFurtherInfo :Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{

                        Button(action: {
                            
                            showFurtherInfo = true

                              }) {
                            Image(systemName: "figure.walk").renderingMode(.original)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                               
                        }
                        .alert(isPresented:$showFurtherInfo) {
                            Alert(
                                title: Text("Important message"),
                                message: Text("Important Info"),
                                dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss"))
                            )
                        }
}
```

I want to stop this refreshing behaviour on alert, please. Basically I just need help decoupling the variable which controls the alert being shown, from this view

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? Without your custom types, no one can copy/paste and test this code.

Comment: Have done this now

Comment: This example does not demonstrate "navigat[ing] the user back up to the root view" -- it's just one view.

Comment: @jnpdx This view is shown as a result of navigating to this view via a nav link. What I'm saying is that dismissing an alert will take you back up this navlink chain. I have no idea how to show this code or this behaviour without including my whole project or a video. The issue is that the variable which is used to show the alert is a state variable. All I need is for someone to tell me how to decouple the alert from the view refreshing state variable, I can't include my whole nav link chain or someone is going to shut the question for there being too much code

Comment: There is no need to show this behaviour. I just need help to stop that state variable refreshing this current view. That will happen with this example, there's no need to show the navigation chain.

Comment: There must be more going on. I can write an example with `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` and a child view with an `Alert` that *does not* exhibit this behavior (I just tried in Xcode). Therefore, there must be something going on that is different in your code. No one will shut down the question for "too much code" if you pare down your code for a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Well I really have no idea what to do in this situation? Do I share the link to the GitHub repo?

Comment: You could, but that is generally not looked upon kindly by users here. What you should probably do is copy your code to a new project (or make a branch) and then pare away code until you have only enough to present the issue, then submit that here. It'll involve some work, for sure, but on the way, you may discover the solution to your own issue, to, which is another value of going through the process.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid refreshing you have to move everything (you don't want to be refreshed) into separated view. Rendering engine will see that the view does not depend on modified state and will not re-render it.

Ie. it would be like

```
OtherView()     // << move everything inside !!
 .alert(isPresented:$showFurtherInfo) {
    Alert(
        title: Text("Important message"),
        message: Text("Important Info"),
        dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss"))
    )
 }
```

*Note: the `OtherView` (named here) will be re-created anyway, because it is just called in computed property, but its `body` will not be called.*